# How to access servos using pins other than GPIO 2&3

Tags: pi-4, i2c, servo

I have an adafruit pca9685 16-servo controller. I was using this guide to control it: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi/using-the-adafruit-library

Particularly my code looks something like the following

```
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
import time 
kit = ServoKit(channels=16)

while True:
    kit.servo[0].angle = 180
    time.sleep(5)
    kit.servo[0].angle = 0
    time.sleep(5)
```

And that all works fine for me if GPIO 2&3 are connected to SDA & SCL respectively.

Now i wanted to get a little creative. I wanted to use GPIO 10 and 9 to control the servo board and have GPIO 2&3 be used somewhere else (it would make the wiring cleaner looking for me and generally I dont want to be stuck using "pin X" only for "purpose Y").

So I moved SDA & SCL to GPIO 9 & 10 respectively, but now my python code freaks out throwing:

"ValueError: No I2C Device at address: 0x40"

From the file "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py"

I did some research into this and the following website makes it seem as if GPIO 2&3 are the ONLY pins that can be used for I2C: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c, but I wanted to confirm with the community if there is some work around to user other pins?

It is clear to me that I2C and adafruit by default are checking pins 2&3, seeing as (2,3) is never passed as an argument in my code, and I was hopeful that there might be a configuration file or setting that can be changed to support other pins.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [`device tree`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) to accomplish this.

You may also need to make some changes to the AdaFruit software. It's likely using the default `i2c1` channel - you'll have to locate this in the software, and change it to match the `i2c` channel you choose (as shown below).

RPi 4 gives you a choice of 6 hardware-based `i2c` channels. These are available through the `device tree` and its `overlays`. These are declared & configured in `/boot/config.txt`. The detailed instructions/documentation for this is mostly in this [README file](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README).

Suggest you read this (README) file first - esp the introductory sections, Afterwards, scroll down in the file until you reach a section that begins with the line `Name:   i2c3`. I'll *guess* the most likely substitutes for `i2c1` in your case are the `dtoverlays` for `i2c3` - `i2c6`. Read through these & select the GPIO pins that suit you. The README file will show you the format & available options for the overlay you choose.

For example, if you choose `i2c4`, you will edit your `/boot/config.txt` file to add the following line:

```
dtoverlay=i2c4,pins_6_7     # *physical* pin #'s 31 & 26
```

You will also need to add pullups (approx 2Kohm each) to those pins - unless your AdaFruit hardware includes them.

Changes to `/boot/config.txt` will become effective after a `reboot`, and will remain in effect until you remove (or comment) the `dtoverlay` you added, and `reboot` again.

Comment: Note that in order to then use Adafruit's Servokit library with the non-standard I2C bus you need https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_Extended_Bus

Answer (score 1):

These are the only accessible pins with hardware support for I²C on most Pi (the Pi4 has additional ports e.g. to enable the i2c3 bus `dtoverlay=i2c3`)

You can use the `dtoverlay=i2c-gpio` for software I²C on other pins.

All of these will require pullup and changes to the code.